# How can I assign a string to a char* pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am a newbie to C and it took me 2 hours to figure out the problem.

```
void helper(char* a, char* b){
    a = malloc(strlen(b));
    memcpy(a, b, strlen(b));
    printf("%s %s\n", a, b);
}

int main(){
    char* b = "hello";
    char* a;
    helper(a, b);
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

While `a` is always `null`. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: `helper(a, b);` does not change `a`.  Need something like `a = helper(b);`  (BTW, need allocation space for the null character too)

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: this is a common problem.  C is pass by value, and helper doesn't change a on exit.  So, you need to change helper to be like this: `void helper(char** a, char* b)`, and the rest of your code to handle the extra level of indirection

Comment: Change to [like this](http://ideone.com/THwkwD)

Comment: What is `null`? You mean _null pointer_ or "equals the macro `NULL`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt change a inside the function. when you did malloc a received new address.

```
void helper(char **a,  char *b){
    *a = malloc(strlen(b)+1); //+1 for the \0 in the end of b
    strcpy(*a, b);
    printf("%s %s\n", *a, b);
}

int main(void){
    char *b = "hello";
    char *a;
    helper(&a, b);
    printf("%s\n", a);
   }
```

And in you code you didnt use free.. You have to free all the pointers that you did malloc...

so add `free(a)` in the end of the main.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand c is copying value for argument!

Answer (score 4):

In `main()`, `a` and `b` are pointers.

`helper(a, b);` gives a copy of pointer `a` and a copy of pointer  `b` to `helper()` as part of the call to `helper()`.

The function completes.

The `a` in `main()` is not updated/changed by the call `helper(a, b)`.  Neither is `b` changed.

---

Code needs a new approach of which there are several good ones.  Example: Use the return value of `helper2()`.

```
char *helper2(const char *source);

int main(void) {
  const char* b = "hello";
  char* a = helper2(b);
  printf("<%s>", a);
  free(a);
}
```

Now create `helper2()`.  Code template follows:

```
#include <...>      // whats includes are needed.
#include <...>      
char *helper2(const char *source) {
  size_t size_needed = ....; // length + 1 for the null character
  char *destination = ...'   // allocate
  if (destination ...) {     // Successful allocation? 
    memcpy(destination, ...., ...); // copy - include null character
  }
  return ...                        // What should be returned here?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've missed the fact that `main()` passes a copy of `a` to `helper()` by value.   So the `a` in `helper()` is a completely different variable (even though you've given it the same name) - it has a different address.

The change of `a` in `helper()` therefore does not affect the `a` in `main()` at all.

Regardless of what `helper()` does, `main()` exhibits undefined behaviour.  `a` is uninitialised, so passing its value to `helper()` gives undefined behaviour.   Passing it to `printf()` gives undefined behaviour for the same reason.

The `printf()` call in `helper()` also has undefined behaviour, since `%s` causes `printf()` to expect a string terminated by a `'\0'`, but the `memcpy()` call has not copied such a thing to `a`.   Practically, `printf()` will probably keep stepping from `a` through random memory until it happens to find a byte with zero value.  This may result in garbage output or (if there is no such byte in memory) an obscure program crash.

A partial fix of your code would be to make the change of `a` in `helper()` visible to `main()`.   For example;

```
/*   Danger:  This code still has undefined behaviour */

void helper(char **a, char* b)
    /*  note usage of extra * on every usage of a in this function  */
{
    *a = malloc(strlen(b));
    memcpy(*a, b, strlen(b));
    printf("%s %s\n", *a, b);
}

int main()
{
    char* b = "hello";
    char* a;
    helper(&a, b);      /*  note use of ampersand here */
    printf("%s", a);
    free(a);            /*  a has been malloc()ed, so free() it */

       /*  using a here will give undefined behaviour, since it is free()d  */
}
```

This code makes the changes to `a` in `helper()` visible to `main()`, by use of pointers.

The problem with this partially fixed code code is that `%s` still causes `printf` to expect that `a` to be terminated with a trailing `'\0'`, but the `memcpy()` does not copy such a trailing `'\0'`.   So both `printf()` calls (in both `helper()` and `main()`) still have undefined behaviour.

To fix this, we need to change `helper()` to

```
void helper(char **a, char* b)
{
    *a = malloc(strlen(b) + 1);
    memcpy(*a, b, strlen(b) + 1);
    printf("%s %s\n", *a, b);
}
```

which allocates a larger buffer, and copies the content of `b` - with its contained `'\0'` into that additional length.

An alternative is to use `strcpy()` instead of `memcpy()`.

```
void helper(char **a, char* b)
{
    *a = malloc(strlen(b) + 1);
    strcpy(*a, b);
    printf("%s %s\n", *a, b);
}
```

The only difference is that `strcpy()` copies characters until it finds the trailing `'\0'` in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed variables, to be clear. What @chux said, is value of variable 'a' changed, but value of variable 'x' - not.

```
void helper(char* a, char* b){
    a = malloc(strlen(b));
    memcpy(a, b, strlen(b));
    printf("%s %s\n", a, b);
}

int main(){
    char* y = "hello";
    char* x;
    helper(x, y);
    printf("%s", x);
}
```

UPD: This is an original code. I just renamed variables in order to disambiguate variables naming, and to do explanations more clear. The problem, as it was pointed by @chux, variable x sent by value, and so cannot be changed in function main.

Comment: @David Bowling, it should be a comment, but I can't post a comment with code. It will bad formatted. I see here a common problem, that new programmers use same names for different variables, and this confuse them. This is also make explanations too hard.

Comment: @downvoted, I see. But this guy sent char pointer by value and expect it to be changed. I answered this point.

Comment: @BorisT-- that is a good point. You should revise this into a true answer. Maybe the downvote will be reversed.

Comment: @David Bowling - thank you. I updated text. English is my problem (hope temporary). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake I saw is that you have ever to allocate    strlen(foo)+1. the correct size for copy a string is this. Than call strcpy() or memset +1 . But with strings I ever use strcpy() on my mind is more performant:

```
  char *strcpy(char *a , const char*b)
  {
       while(*a++=*b++)
                   ;
       return a;
  }
```

then (this is a very trivial version, the real one has more checks)

```
  char * memcpy(a,b,n)
   {
       while(n--)
       *a++=*b++;
       return a;
   }
```

there is a counter more to decrease; With memset you have also to call strlen() for get the length, and add one. With strcpy() is not required.  So yes, the differences are not appreciable, but there are, but what is appreciable is the redeability, the clearness of the code all this with (teorethical, unless some compiler optimization) better performance